# Hive table for Syslog data

Tags: hadoop, schema, hive, syslog, impala

I am trying to create a Hive external table such that a syslog message is broken up into four columns: timestamp, host, programname+pid, and message. I want to do this without resorting to the Regex serde because I also want the table to be usable by Impala (that doesn't support the Regex Serde).

Trouble is if I define the schema with four fields and specify "\040" as the field separator, I end up with only first string of the message. For example, this log line:

```
2014-01-01T04:00:00 myhost sshd[9008]: joe logged in from 192.168.1.1 with password ....
```

gets mapped as:

```
timestamp: 2014-01-01T04:00:00
host: myhost
prog: sshd[9008]:
msg: joe
```

the "logged in from ...." gets chopped off.

Given that there are four columns, is there a way to tell Hive to put the remainder of the fields in the last column instead of leaving them out? A greedy option?

Thanks

Comment: I solved it by defining a Hive table that has only one column, for the entire log line and then use regexp_extract in Impala to create a view.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by defining a Hive table that has only one column, for the entire log line and then use regexp_extract in Impala to create a view.

In Hive, create a table as:

```
create EXTERNAL TABLE hive_syslog_table (logline STRING) LOCATION '/logs';
```

Then in Impala:

```
create view syslog_view as select regexp_extract(logline,'(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(.+)',1) ts, regexp_extract(logline,'(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(.+)',2) host, regexp_extract(logline,'(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)([:\\/\\[\\ ])\\s+(.+)',3) prog, regexp_extract(logline,'(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(\\S+)\\s+(.+)',4) msg from hive_syslog_table;
```